# How to redirect stdout and stderr to rsyslog permamently in Linux

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I use an embedded Linux build in Yocto. I would like none of the applications running on the system to display information in the console. I would like to redirect these logs to syslog, or eventually, to some other regular file. I know that in my scripts or applications I can log directly to rsyslog, but changing sources of all applications in the system is too laborious. Is it possible to force redirection of stdout and stderr to rsyslog or eventually to some other common file permamently?

Answer (score 3):

You can write to the `logger`. By default it will use a facility and priority of `user.notice` but this can be changed with suitable command flags.

```
logger 'this is a test'

ps -ef 2>&1 | logger
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a shell with redirection:

```
$ bash >out 2>err
ls
exit
```

Now, all the output from the commands you issued in that shell will go into `out` file and all errors into `err`.